# LG Nexus 5X can't see in Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, nexus-5, lg, google-nexus

I have a LG Nexus 5x smartphone, I would like to use to on device debugging in Android Studio on my Windows 10 Computer. I turn on the dubugger options on my phone, but the Android Studio can't see that. From where can I downlod the USB driver, that fixs my problem?

Comment: try this http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: Do you realize that StackOverflow is not place for such questions? Ask here - http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Install Google USB Drivers on SDK Tools
- Enable  Debugging Mode on Developer Settings.
- Go to Device Manager and check drivers status. (Probably you can see warning icon on ADB Interface Driver.) Select ADB Interface driver and click update. Choose "Browse my computer for driver software" and set folder path like "D:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk" .
- After installation, check your device and confirm to USB debugging.

  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem of compatibility between Windows 10 and Nexus 5x/6p phones. You'll need to manually download this driver (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html).

Find "Devices and Printers" in control panel, right-click on "MTP", and choose properties.

Click "ADB interface", then click "Properties"

Go to "Driver" tab and update driver with the file you just downloaded. (Make sure you unzip them first)

Source: [How to install Nexus 5X & 6P USB (ADB) Drivers for Android Studio on Windows 10](http://www.schang.xyz/articles/how-to-install-nexus-5x-6p-usb-adb-drivers-for-android-studio-on-windows-10)